# How to load gif image url with Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I can load a gif image url, but not able to load with Glide using this code.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load("gif imageurl")
     .asGif()
     .crossFade()
     .into(imageview);
```

How to load a gif image from server using Glide?

Comment: What is your `Glide version` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(R.raw.sample_gif)
     .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(yourImageView))
```

or so, try to move the call of the method asGif before the loading

```
Glide.with(context)
     .asGif()
     .load("gif image url")
     .crossFade()
     .into(imageview);
```

Comment: I tried but for example with https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952 it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below code:

```
ImageView gif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gif);
Glide.with(this)
     .asGif()
     .load("gif image url")
     .into(gif);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try on this way it's work fine.

```
ImageView im_gif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im_gif);
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.gif_logo).into(im_gif);
```

You can add your `gif image` file to `resource/raw` folder.and set that name into load method.